# jquery sort by date or text first

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have this script which sorts dates

```
  function (list) {
        var $list = $(list);
        var elems = $.makeArray($list.find("li"));
        elems.sort(function(a, b) {
            return new Date($(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate")) < new     Date($(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate"));
        });

        $list.html(elems);
   }
```

And the html

```
<ul id="theList">
<li><span class=".to-date" data-todate="2015-01">2015-01</span></li>
<li><span class=".to-date" data-todate="2017-01">2015-01</span></li>
<li><span class=".to-date" data-todate="now">now</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to sort the items containing "now" in the todate attr to be sorted first. How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sort` function you can check if `$(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate")` equals `now` and if this is the case then return true. If `$(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate")` equals `now`, then return false. Otherwise use the standard comparison logic.

```
function (list) {
    var $list = $(list);
    var elems = $.makeArray($list.find("li"));
    elems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var $aStr = $(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");
        var $bStr = $(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate");

        if ($aStr === 'now') {
            return true;
        } else if ($bStr === 'now') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return new Date($aStr) < new Date($bStr);
        }
    });

    $list.html(elems);
}
```

Comment: I dont know if this alters the question but what if i want to put the items containing sort in the top and and sort them form another data value ?

Comment: Do you mean the items with 'now' in the date column? If you want to sort them on a secondary field, then you can do this by adding a condition where `$aStr` and `$bStr` both contain 'now' and compare the secondary field within this branch.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick

```
elems.sort(function(a, b) {            
    if (($(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate") === "now")) 
            return -1;
    if (($(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate") === "now"))
            return 1;
    return new Date($(a).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate")) < new Date($(b).find(".to-date").attr("data-todate"));
    });
```

Hope it helps

Dan